# Same SQL query - giving different output

Tags: sql, excel

In SQL I'm querying the database between a date range but the output is giving dates 4 years later. I'm using Excel - the `Get External Data` wizard.

```
SELECT *
,convert(varchar(3), DATENAME(MONTH, CreditNote_Date)) as Fin_Month
,datepart(wk, CreditNote_Date) as as Fin_Week
FROM 
--blah
WHERE -- blah
AND (CreditNote_Date between convert (datetime, '2014-12-29 00:00:00', 102) 
and convert (datetime, '2015-12-27 00:00:00', 102))
```

However when the same query is executed in SQL Server Management Studio I get the correct 2014/2015 dates. They seem to correspond to the same rows. Some lines have been commented out due to confidentiality but do ask if more info is required.

[image: Wrong year / dates returned]
[image: correct dates reutnred]

Comment: how are your dates saved in the database?

Comment: The Data Type is `smalldatetime` - is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @hgeop . . . Don't use `between` with datetime values.  I would suggest you read this blog, https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common, and then code your SQL accordingly.  You will at least prevent future problems this way.

Comment: format is like dd/mm/yyyy for when it's like 11/06/2015 for today's date, but it also includes things like hours, minutes, seconds etc... so excel might be having issues converting your data while sql server management studio is rendering them normally

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a little wacky, but if you are working with excel, try replacing whatever date conversion you are using to match the below.

```
select cast(getdate() as varchar(10))
```

I've had a fair bit of trouble with excel dates in the past and discovered excel implicitly converts this format pretty well.

Comment: It's very strange - I have the exact same query in another Excel file and that's working correctly. I paste that table into the file I need it in and the 2019 dates are produced...

Comment: @hgeop That would suggest the destination column in excel is formatted wrong. Try formatting the destination as text.